# Event return null value when user enter decimal on input type number

Tags: javascript, html, input

**Edit** working on Firefox, only Chrome bug (and maybe others)

I try to get all event from a simple `<input type="number" step="any" />` :

```js
$('input[type=number]').on('input', function() {
  $('#value').text($(this).val())
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="number" step="any"/>
<br/>
<strong>Value:</strong> <span id="value"></span>
```

All append good when I press, or update the number. But when I try to put a decimal point `.` the value is `null`.

I use jQuery here, but the problem is the same with Vanilla JS.

Comment: It's working for me in the snippet (Firefox).

Comment: Ho.. you right, it's only on Chrome.

Comment: @squint, parseFloat(null) === NaN

Comment: @Arthur: Yep, you're right. He isn't getting the value.

Comment: Looks like it's not a bug in Chrome but in fact it is behaving [according to the spec](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/infrastructure.html#valid-floating-point-number). When there's a decimal, a number is required after it. So technically it's a bug in Firefox.

Comment: Yeah, or on the spec ^^ cause it's very weird

Comment: Actually, it seems that Firefox gives the value but ignores the single trailing decimal. So a partial fix would be to only set the `.text()` when the `.val()` is not an empty string. Chrome will still fail when pasting something like `12.` into the field, but it will be nicer when typing anyway. `var v = this.value; if (v) $('#value').text(v);` A little weird when deleting from the end though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think it is issue with `type` of `input` field, `decimal point` (the dot) is not a number but it is necessary for numbers, so i guess it is the glitch in the matrix.

here is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/39eoepoc/) where type is text and it is working fine.

Comment: input type number allow decimal (cause `step` attribute handle `.1` value) but the event is bugged on Chrome. :/

Comment: wait i am editing the answer, think out of box friend, it is a basic flaw.

Comment: Yeah, I have send a feedback to Google team. Hope they'll do something on the future

Answer (score 1):

The closest I can get is:

```js
$('input[type=number]').on('input', function() {
  $(this).select();

  var value = window.getSelection().toString();
  window.getSelection().empty();

  $('#value').text(value);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="number" step="any"/>
<br/>
<strong>Value:</strong> <span id="value"></span>
```

Notice that when you type something, the field loses its focus...